# Remove/reset prefix in redis

Tags: redis

I have little knowledge of redis or how it works. Another app wrote this data but they are clueless on how to fix my problem. So please be specific.

The app had the option for redis to set a prefix. I decided to use 'abc'. I turns out now that I should not have used anything for the prefix and just used an empty string ''. I have 5 years of data in the redis files I'd rather not lose.

How can I reset the prefix from abc to ''.

Thanks,

Comment: You only tagged "redis". What kind of prefix are you talking about? Is it inside the DB or within your client? In regards to your comment of not losing data - make a backup before you try anything!

Comment: I am not sure. I didn't write the code and the writers aren't being very forthcoming. One of the configuration options they give me is 'prefix'. I assume that it's inside the database. When I use the original prefix with a new update of the code I can see the data but it won't add new values. They said it was a mistake to use the prefix in the first place. I don't know enough about redis to know if there is any form of data definition that would allow me to dump a few values to see what they look like. And how do I back up redis short of making a copy of the data files? Thanks for your help